# Error while converting csv to parquet using EMR cluster

Tags: hive, hiveql, emr, parquet

I have created an EMR cluster with Hive script as one of the execution step added.
Here's how my HIVE script looks like:

--Create Hive external Table for existing data
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE calls_csv
(
  `id` int,
  `campaign_id` int,
  `campaign_name` string,
  `offer_id` int,
  `offer_name` string,
  `is_offer_not_found` int,
  `ivr_key` string,
  `call_uuid` string,
  `a_leg_uuid` string,
  `a_leg_request_uuid` string,
  `to_number` string,
  `promo_id` int,
  `description` string,
  `call_type` string,
  `answer_type` string,
  `agent_id` int,
  `from_number` string,
  `from_caller_name` string,
  `from_line_type` string,
  `from_state` string,
  `from_city` string,
  `from_country` string,
  `from_zip` string,
  `from_latitude` string,
  `from_longitude` string,
  `b_leg_uuid` string,
  `b_leg_number` string,
  `b_leg_duration` int,
  `b_leg_bill_rate` double,
  `b_leg_bill_duration` int,
  `b_leg_total_cost` double,
  `b_leg_hangup_cause` string,
  `b_leg_start_time` string,
  `b_leg_answer_time` string,
  `b_leg_end_time` string,
  `b_leg_active` tinyint,
  `bill_rate` double,
  `bill_duration` int,
  `hangup_cause` string,
  `start_time` string,
  `answer_time` string,
  `end_time` string,
  `status` string,
  `selected_ivr_keys` string,
  `processed_ivr_keys` string,
  `filter_id` int,
  `filter_name` string,
  `ivr_action` string,
  `selected_zip_code` string,
  `processed_zip_code` string,
  `duration` int,
  `payout` double,
  `min_duration` int,
  `connected_duration` int,
  `provider_cost` double,
  `caller_id_cost` double,
  `total_revenue` double,
  `total_cost` double,
  `total_profit` double,
  `publisher_id` int,
  `publisher_name` string,
  `publisher_revenue` double,
  `publisher_cost` double,
  `publisher_profit` double,
  `advertiser_id` int,
  `advertiser_name` string,
  `advertiser_cost` double,
  `is_test` tinyint,
  `is_sale` tinyint,
  `is_repeat` tinyint,
  `is_machine_detection` tinyint,
  `no_of_call_transfer` int,
  `offer_ivr_status` tinyint,
  `file_url` string,
  `algo` string,
  `callback_service_status` tinyint,
  `hangup_service_status` tinyint,
  `sms_uuid` string,
  `number_name` string,
  `keyword` string,
  `keywordmatchtype` string,
  `created_at` string,
  `updated_at` string,
  `ymdhm` bigint 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar'     = '\"')
   LOCATION 's3://calls-csv/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',
              'serialization.null.format'='');

msck repair table calls_csv;

-- Lets now create an external table to Parquet format
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  calls_parquet (
    `id` int,
  `campaign_id` int,
  `campaign_name` string,
  `offer_id` int,
  `offer_name` string,
  `is_offer_not_found` int,
  `ivr_key` string,
  `call_uuid` string,
  `a_leg_uuid` string,
  `a_leg_request_uuid` string,
  `to_number` string,
  `promo_id` int,
  `description` string,
  `call_type` string,
  `answer_type` string,
  `agent_id` int,
  `from_number` string,
  `from_caller_name` string,
  `from_line_type` string,
  `from_state` string,
  `from_city` string,
  `from_country` string,
  `from_zip` string,
  `from_latitude` string,
  `from_longitude` string,
  `b_leg_uuid` string,
  `b_leg_number` string,
  `b_leg_duration` int,
  `b_leg_bill_rate` double,
  `b_leg_bill_duration` int,
  `b_leg_total_cost` double,
  `b_leg_hangup_cause` string,
  `b_leg_start_time` string,
  `b_leg_answer_time` string,
  `b_leg_end_time` string,
  `b_leg_active` tinyint,
  `bill_rate` double,
  `bill_duration` int,
  `hangup_cause` string,
  `start_time` string,
  `answer_time` string,
  `end_time` string,
  `status` string,
  `selected_ivr_keys` string,
  `processed_ivr_keys` string,
  `filter_id` int,
  `filter_name` string,
  `ivr_action` string,
  `selected_zip_code` string,
  `processed_zip_code` string,
  `duration` int,
  `payout` double,
  `min_duration` int,
  `connected_duration` int,
  `provider_cost` double,
  `caller_id_cost` double,
  `total_revenue` double,
  `total_cost` double,
  `total_profit` double,
  `publisher_id` int,
  `publisher_name` string,
  `publisher_revenue` double,
  `publisher_cost` double,
  `publisher_profit` double,
  `advertiser_id` int,
  `advertiser_name` string,
  `advertiser_cost` double,
  `is_test` tinyint,
  `is_sale` tinyint,
  `is_repeat` tinyint,
  `is_machine_detection` tinyint,
  `no_of_call_transfer` int,
  `offer_ivr_status` tinyint,
  `file_url` string,
  `algo` string,
  `callback_service_status` tinyint,
  `hangup_service_status` tinyint,
  `sms_uuid` string,
  `number_name` string,
  `keyword` string,
  `keywordmatchtype` string,
  `created_at` string,
  `updated_at` string,
  `ymdhm` bigint)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://calls-parquet/';

--Time to convert and export. This step will run for a long time, depending on your data size and cluster size. 
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE calls_parquet SELECT * FROM calls_csv

Below is the error I am getting when I run this step on the EMR cluster

Status :FAILED

Details : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Error moving: s3://calls-parquet/.hive-staging_hive_2018-03-20_07-09-28_592_6773618098932115163-1/-ext-10000 into: s3://calls-parquet/

JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None

Arguments : hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f s3://calls-scripts/converToParquetHive.sql -d INPUT=s3://calls-csv -d OUTPUT=s3://calls-parquet
Action on failure: Continue

Comment: Thanks Harsh.Done

Comment: If I remove the INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE calls_parquet SELECT * FROM calls_csv statement from the script, it runs fine.

Comment: Do you have the complete error stack trace?